# How to read image file at documents directory from ios webview

Tags: html, ios, webview

I am downloading image file and write to documents directory like below:

```
NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString  *objURL = @"http://test.test.com/file/image.png";
NSURL     *objurl = [NSURL URLWithString:objURL];
NSData    *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:objurl];

NSString *imgFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"image.png"];
[imgData writeToFile:imgFile atomically:YES];
```

In my webView, I loaded a html file from my bundle resource to use in my webView, but how do I have the  tag in html to read the image.png in documents directory?

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="../what/is/the/path/to/use/image.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the URL for this image using an absolute path with a `file://` scheme:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)[0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/image.png", documentsDirectory];
```

You could then run some javascript to update the `src` tag to update it to the new path:

```
NSString *javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var imageElement = document.getElementById('localFile'); imageElement.setAttribute('src', '%@');", filePath];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

In your HTML the path would look like something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img id="localFile" src="file:///var/mobile/Applications/3D7D43E8-FA5E-4B19-B74C-669F7D1F3093/Documents/image.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the screenshot from Safari Remote debugger [here](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-E04kqghLhYk/V7W1aWfKtTI/AAAAAAAAGUo/xavby-jUx7oIP7nGHXa42-f1GeIq5LaWACL0B/w1500-h162-no/Console.png)

Comment: But image can be loaded from the app bundle

Comment: Safari console shows error 'Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of evaluating JavaScript, I just write down a placeholder in my html content, and replace it directly w/ the content needed:

```
NSString *htmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) {
  // handle error
  return;
}

NSString *imageFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample_image.png"];
NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageFilePath];
NSString *sampleImageReplacement =
  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\" />", [imageFileURL absoluteString]];

// Replace the placeholder w/ real content,
//   and of course, we can also replace it w/ empty string
//   if the image cannot be found.
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%sample_image%"
                                                   withString:sampleImageReplacement];
...
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the images from the app bundle but you can not load the images from the documents directory directly.

But there is a work around.

Use [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) to create a InAppHttpServer and you can access the images in documents directory using http URL in web view.

or else

Convert the image into base64 and load the image using `evaluatejavascript` of webview

```
document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind image source from beginning. You will have to do it via JavaScript.

You need to pass the path of the image to UIWebView by evaluating JS. Here you can pass the path of your image and JS will load the image into respective HTML tag.