# Loading an image file from iOS tmp/ folder in WKWebView from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

So the setup is images are created on the native side (Swift) of my application, which are then saved to the Temporary storage folder in the sandbox. How can I load that image from `JavaScript`? I've been able to use `loadFileURL(_: allowingReadAccessTo:)` on my `WKWebView` to load the image on top of everything, but I wanted to be able to reference that image in my `JavaScript` to do stuff with it - for now, just loading it into an img element. I can get its full URL passed in easy enough with `evaluateJavaScript:` too, but that doesn't seem to help. How is that done?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to make it work in WKWebview? I m using WKWebview and it doesnt bring in the image.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help:

```
//Get the file path 
NSString *temporaryStorageDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(TemporaryStorageDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES)[0]; NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/image.png", temporaryStorageDirectory];

//Access the files using javascript source tag using the image file path 
NSString *javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var localImage = document.getElementById('localFile'); imageElement.setAttribute('src', '%@');", filePath]; [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

It's from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494752/how-to-read-image-file-at-documents-directory-from-ios-webview).