# Swift : Is there a way to play local video in WKWebview with local html

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I'm making some app using WKWebView. In this app, I capture some photos and video in native.

I saved them into document folder and now I want to show them in local HTML.

I found a way to show images by encoding base64, but I can't do that video.

I tried to use loadFileURL, it works but it shows only video, not other HTML codes.

and I tried video tags but it didn`t work. (It shows only controls)

Is there a way to append local video with other HTML codes?
or other solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494752/how-to-read-image-file-at-documents-directory-from-ios-webview/39032697#39032697

Comment: @PPL thanx comment. but it could encode video too?

Comment: @JackKim Try this. In your html file. `..... <video controls><source src="<#VIDEO_FILE_URL#>"></source></video> .....`. Load it with `String.init(contentsOfUrl:)`. Then replace `"<#VIDEO_FILE_URL#>"` with your video document folder url. Then use `webView..loadHTMLString(yourSubstitutedHTMLString, baseURL: nil)`

Comment: @CosmosMan OMG! thx! that could be one of solutions! i'll try it!

Comment: @CosmosMan i tried it. but it doesn`t work... so i just pass video encoded by base64